# How to rotate IAM Access Keys which were created using AWS CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

We have a IAM User Access Key created via CDK using `CfnAccessKey` construct.

However, this access key hasn't been rotated for more than 90 days so we want to rotate it, but through CDK only with minimal interruption and effort each time going forward.

Is there any way to achieve that via AWS CDK?

Comment: Posted a solution, if it worked for you, could you pleaser accept it as an answer so that it helps others in the future with the similar problem.

Comment: Sure Jatin. The answer looks like it would work perfectly. However, due to our schedules and other priorities I did not get time to try out the solution. Once I empirically try it out and succeed will accept the answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to setup `CfnAccessKey` or `aws_iam.AccessKey` construct  `serial` props in order to setup rotation. **Everytime you need to rotate, just increment the serial value to inform cloudformation for rotation**

According to [Docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v1/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-iam.CfnAccessKey.html#serial)

> This value is specific to CloudFormation and can only be incremented .
> Incrementing this value notifies CloudFormation that you want to rotate your access key. When you update your stack, CloudFormation will replace the existing access key with a new key.

During instantiation

```
// The code below shows an example of how to instantiate this type.
// The values are placeholders you should change.
import * as iam from '@aws-cdk/aws-iam';
const cfnAccessKey = new iam.CfnAccessKey(this, 'MyCfnAccessKey', {
  userName: 'userName',

  // the properties below are optional
  serial: 1,
  status: 'Active',
});
```

For rotating keys

```
// The code below shows an example of how to instantiate this type.
// The values are placeholders you should change.
import * as iam from '@aws-cdk/aws-iam';
const cfnAccessKey = new iam.CfnAccessKey(this, 'MyCfnAccessKey', {
  userName: 'userName',

  // the properties below are optional
  serial: 2,
  status: 'Active',
});
```

Update 1) using [L2 construct (`aws_iam.AccessKey`)](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_iam.AccessKey.html)

```
import { CfnOutput, Duration, Stack, StackProps } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { Construct } from 'constructs';
import { aws_iam as iam } from 'aws-cdk-lib';
import { AccessKeyStatus, User } from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-iam';


export class CdkStackoverflowStack extends Stack {
  constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
    super(scope, id, props);
    const existingUserFromName = User.fromUserName(this, 'user-from-name-id', 'cdk-stackoverflow')
    const cfnAccessKey = new iam.AccessKey(this, 'MyCfnAccessKey', {
      user: existingUserFromName,
      // the properties below are optional
      serial: 2,
      status: AccessKeyStatus.ACTIVE,
    })
    new CfnOutput(this, 'accessSecretKey', { value: cfnAccessKey.secretAccessKey.unsafeUnwrap().toString() })
    new CfnOutput(this, 'accessKeyID', { value: cfnAccessKey.accessKeyId.toString() })
  }
}
```

**Update 2:- [ as per comments] Keys created with cdk without serial value**

Created user from console called as cdk-stakcoverflow without access key.
Created  access key from CDK without setting `serial` value. observe the comments

```
 export class CdkStackoverflowStack extends Stack {
      constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);
        const existingUserFromName = User.fromUserName(this, 'user-from-name-id', 'cdk-stackoverflow')
        const cfnAccessKey = new iam.AccessKey(this, 'MyCfnAccessKey', {
          user: existingUserFromName,
          // the properties below are optional
          // serial: 5,
          // status: AccessKeyStatus.ACTIVE,
        })
        new CfnOutput(this, 'accessSecretKey', { value: cfnAccessKey.secretAccessKey.unsafeUnwrap().toString() })
        new CfnOutput(this, 'accessKeyID', { value: cfnAccessKey.accessKeyId.toString() })
      }
    }
```

Take a note of ID either from console or terminal
Now uncomment the serial line, and redeploy the stack, you will see that your key is updated, atleast in my environment this is being rotated :)

```
 export class CdkStackoverflowStack extends Stack {
      constructor(scope: Construct, id: string, props?: StackProps) {
        super(scope, id, props);
        const existingUserFromName = User.fromUserName(this, 'user-from-name-id', 'cdk-stackoverflow')
        const cfnAccessKey = new iam.AccessKey(this, 'MyCfnAccessKey', {
          user: existingUserFromName,
          // the properties below are optional
          serial: 5,
          status: AccessKeyStatus.ACTIVE,
        })
        new CfnOutput(this, 'accessSecretKey', { value: cfnAccessKey.secretAccessKey.unsafeUnwrap().toString() })
        new CfnOutput(this, 'accessKeyID', { value: cfnAccessKey.accessKeyId.toString() })
      }
    }
```

**Note :- you don't need to Output access keys its just for sure confirmation that keys added by cdk is added, you can delete your existing key which is not managed by cdk.**

Comment: I have added the serial property with number 1 and redeployed the Cloudformation stack via CDK. However, still my keys haven't gotten rotated. Please note that I already have an IAM user and access key deployed without the serial property and now I'm just trying to update same. Please let me where am I going wrong.

Comment: Its not like the gets haven't rotated, the already created keys are not in cloudformation stack, hence cdk cannot keep track of it, in such case cdk will add a second key to along with existing key.
I tried to replicate your use case, where I have created a iam user with access keys from console, and then i tried to rotate, to my expectations cdk added another key along with existing key, and when I increased my number, the key added by cdk was rotated. I have confirmed this by looking into my console.

Comment: Btw, there is an L2 construct which abstracts on a more higher level. updated my answer

Comment: Hmm. I just checked my IAM user again to verify it again and I see that the access key has not been updated. I think the reason might be that I have just added `serial:1` property to existing access key and haven't incremented it. Will try updating `serial` to 2 and update here about the results.

Comment: Like I said, when you manage keys from cdk, cdk will add a new key along with existing key, from here on if you increment values it will rotate keys for the key which is created by cdk and not your existing key. 
You can delete your existing key and use cdk created key, and yes when you update serial to 2, cdk will update key only created by cdk and not existing key as it is not part of cdk stack

Comment: Even your question says `how to update keys using aws cdk`, so if you follow how I told cdk is updating keys `created by cdk`.

Comment: Just a clarification (I may not have properly conveyed it in my previous comments) - my key was created by a CDK stack only, but it just did not have the `serial` property initially and I added `serial:1` now,  which did not rotate my access key. I hope my scenario is clear now.

Comment: @RamaRahul, I have updated my answer and follow along with my update, because I successfully verified rotation of keys as per your use case.

Comment: Problem of having two keys both having serials, if you increment any one of them, its not allowed since AWS imposes hard limit of 2 keys per iam user however rotation still creates 3rd key behind the scene before replacement happens. But if you have only one key, during rotation creds from old key becomes invalid before you change service to use new creds from the replacement key. It causes a small outage gap.